# MVC AJAX POST both model and antiforgerytoken not binding the model

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

To commit a form(not a true form, just a div with input fields) via AJAX, I am sending both my (serialized) model and a token from the view. 
However, the model does **not want to bind**, it is not null, but no value is set.
The token is not giving any issues unlike before, so I assume that one passes.

On my action I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Submit(FormModel model)
```

Then my js is:

```
var url = '/MyController/Submit';
        var selector = '#data :input';
        var pagedata = $(selector).serialize();    

        var postData = {
            __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
            jsonRequest:pagedata
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
               alert(1);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                  alert(2);
            }
        });
```

Note: The serialization goes ok, if I put an alert on the Pagedata property it shows the fields correctly.

Comment: Looks like the model data is inside a property named "jsonRequest" in the posted json. Have you tried adding the token directly to `pagedata` and sending that json instead of `postData`?

Comment: Thanks that worked:   data: pagedata + '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + $('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(), If you post it as the answer I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the model data inside a property named `jsonRequest` in the posted json, while MVC will expect the model data as the root of the posted json.

You can add the token as if it were another property of the posted json (It will be ignored when binding to your `FormModel` but it will be used to satisfy the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute).

For example:

```
var selector = '#data :input';
var pagedata = $(selector).serialize();
pagedata = pagedata + '&__RequestVerificationToken=' + $('[name= "__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: pagedata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (error) {
        ...
    }
});
```